# Extract text from IE with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

So I want to be able to extract the some HTML code from a webpage and assign it to a variable with Excel VBA. Here is my example VBA code:

```
Pass = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary_field_value easy-read-display")(0).innerText
```

This returns text, but not the right text from the webpage. In the HTML code, there are a number of fields that look like this:

```
 <div class="ui-body-b summary_field">
<span class="summary_field_name">Username:</span>
<span class="summary_field_value easy-read-display">TestUser</span>

 <div class="ui-body-b summary_field">
    <span class="summary_field_name">Password:</span>
    <span class="summary_field_value easy-read-display">uhQT65$We2</span>
```

So when my code runs, it produces "TestUser". How can I get it to return "uhQT65$We2" which is the password since the class names are the same (summary_field_value easy-read-display)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try this : `Pass = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary_field_value")(1).innerText`

Comment: Wow easy as that. Thanks for the help!